# Screen in Emacs shell: how to detach?

Tags: emacs, gnu-screen, detach

I usually run a shell within Emacs and use it to ssh to a server where I do my work.
After ssh, I use screen to keep a persistent session running.
However, within the Emacs' shell I cannot use `C-a d` to `detach` from the screen session.

**Question:** How do detach from a screen session running within a shell in Emacs?

Comment: I can't start screen in the standard Emcs `shell` buffer: it says `Clear screen capability required.`. How do you run screen in emacs shell?

Comment: @choroba Before running screen, execute the following bash command `TERM=screen-256color`. And then run `screen`. Hopefully it works for you.

Comment: How do you enter any screen commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to detach the screen by preceding the <kbd>C-a</kbd> by <kbd>C-q</kbd> and adding a <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of the screen command:

<kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: That works for me too! Do you know why it works though? It seems like we are inserting the literal characters `^Ad`.

Comment: The `C-q` prevents Emacs from interpreting the `C-a`. Why the `Enter` is needed, I don't know, but I guess Emacs doesn't send the line to the server before you press Enter.